# How to make dropdown using Kendo UI

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, telerik

I'm using Telerik MVC 4. I want to make a combobox and dropdown list. But it always show textbox.

This is Controller

```
[Authorize]
        public JsonResult GetProvinsiByJSON()
        {
            var propinsi = db.Tbl_Propinsi.Where(b => b.flag == "Y").Select(b => new { Value = b.id_propinsi, Text = b.propinsi }).AsEnumerable();
            return Json(propinsi, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is my View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Kota";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_adminLayout.cshtml";
}

<div class="tables">
    <div class="table-responsive bs-example widget-shadow">
        <h4>Data Kota:</h4>
        <div>
            <form> 
                <div class="form-group"> 
                    <label for="kategori">Tambah Kota</label>
                    <br/>
                    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                      .Name("provId")
                      .Placeholder("Pilih Provinsi")
                      .DataTextField("Text")
                      .DataValueField("Value")
                      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" })
                      .Filter("contains")
                              .DataSource(source => { source.Read(read => read.Action("GetProvinsiByJSON", "Lokasi")); })
                    )
                     @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                        .Name("provID")
                        .OptionLabel("Please select Provinsi ...")
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:40%" })
                        .DataTextField("Text")
                        .DataValueField("Value")
                        .Filter("contains")
                        .DataSource(source => { source.Read(read => read.Action("GetProvinsiByJSON", "Lokasi")); })
                    )
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kota" name="kota" placeholder="Nama Kota">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Simpan</button> 
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-bordered"> 
            <thead>
                <tr> 
                <th>No</th> 
                <th>Kota</th>
                <th>Provinsi</th> 
                </thead> 
                <tbody> 

                </tbody> 
        </table> 
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what i get, Just an empty textbox

[image]

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: From my experience, this behavior usually comes from Javascript errors exist on your Kendo UI view. Please check your view page using browser's developer tools and post shown errors here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was most likely to be caused by JavaScript errors or missing required resources needed for Kendo UI.

> In order for the Kendo UI scripts to work as expected, make sure you
>   include a reference to the jQuery library in the document before the
>   scripts.

Please have a look at following links:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites#javascript-prerequisites
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/getting-started#host-kendo-ui-in-your-project

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes thank you, but data in db still can't be populate. Do you know why?